# How do I prevent my cats from urinating everywhere?

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, toilet-training, marking

I have 5 cats (2 males, 3 females, all spayed/neutered).  They all used to be indoor, but because they urinated everywhere, especially one that slept with me, we now keep them outside.  I really miss them.  Is there anyway to keep them from peeing without an expensive investment?

Comment: How much is expensive? There are some litter additives that help.

Comment: Are they urinating on horizontal things (floors, counters, etc) or on vertical things (walls, etc)? Both? Those are distinct behaviors with different causes.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what are they peeing on like @freiheit asked before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without fully knowing the situation, I would guess that this might actually be territorial spraying. Spraying isn't the same thing as pee (I'll spare the details). I hope someone has a better answer but I think chances are that with a mix of males and females, it is probably just too many cats for an indoor space.

To attempt to determine what the source of urine marking is, [I recommend this ASCPA reference](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/virtual-pet-behaviorist/cat-behavior/urine-marking-cats). There are a lot of possibilities and since this has a large scope I'm not sure it makes sense to repeat all that information here.