# Cat has started to occasionally gone to toilet in the living room

Tags: cats, toilet-training

Our cat which is litter trained for 9 months (and also has outside access) has now suddenly gone to the toilet a couple of times in in our living room.

The cat has been spayed and the first time it happened is when we went on holiday and we had a friend come to stay for the week to look after the cats (brother and sister).

What has triggered this behavior and how can we stop it from happening again?

Comment: please see if the following help you any: [one](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3248/my-cat-suddenly-stopped-using-the-litter-box-to-defecate) [two](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/how-can-stop-my-adult-cat-from-urinating-in-inappropriate-places) [three](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/292/how-do-i-prevent-my-cats-from-urinating-everywhere)